# Use workbook file name as a sheetname

Tags: excel, vba

I try to get the sheet name from a file name using code the below, but I'm getting:

> Error subscript out of range

The reason I'm doing this is because each time we download and save as this file, we will rename the file and the same name will be applied to sheet name too. I know that sheet name has a character limit also, can you help me fix that too? Thank you in advance.

```
Sub Sheet_Name_TEST()
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim SelectFile As Variant
Dim SourceName As String

    SelectFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX; *.UTX),*.XLSX; *.UTX", Title:="Select File")
    If SelectFile = False Then Exit Sub

Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(SelectFile)
    SourceName = SourceWB.Name
    If InStr(SourceName, ".") > 0 Then
       SourceName = Left(SourceName, InStr(SourceName, ".") - 1)
       Debug.Print SourceName
    End If
Set sourceWS = SourceWB.Sheets("SourceName")

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set sourceWS = SourceWB.Sheets(SourceName)`

Comment: Silly me, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Everyone has to learn one day, You know? I'm sure from now You won't do this mistake again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Teamothy for pointing out my silly mistake. Got it solved as per below..

```
Sub Sheet_Name_TEST()
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim SelectFile As Variant
Dim SourceName As String

    SelectFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX; *.UTX),*.XLSX; *.UTX", Title:="Select File") 'Select file
    If SelectFile = False Then Exit Sub

Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(SelectFile)
       SourceName = Left((Replace((SourceWB.Name), ".utx", "")), 31) 'Get filename > remove extension > trim to 31 characters only
       Debug.Print SourceName
Set sourceWS = SourceWB.Sheets(SourceName)

End Sub
```